# Prove $y=\frac{\cos(2x)-(t-1)\cos(4x)+t}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} +x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} -x) + t\sin^2(x)} $ is independent of $t$

Tags: trigonometry

> > Prove $$y=\frac{\cos(2x)-(t-1)\cos(4x)+t}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} +x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} -x) + t\sin^2(x)} $$ is independent of $t$

My attempt to reduce both numerator and denominator as much as possible:

Starting off with numerator:

$$ \cos(2x)-(t-1)\cos(4x)+t$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \cos(2x)+(1-t)\cos(4x)+t$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \cos(2x)+\cos(4x)-t\cos(4x)+t$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  2\cos^2(x)-1+2\cos^2(2x)-1-t(2\cos^2(2x)-1)+t$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  2\cos^2(x)-2+2(2\cos^2(x)-1)^2 -2t\cos^2(2x)+2t$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  2\cos^2(x)-2+8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x) + 2 -2t(4\cos^4(x)-4\cos(x)+1) + 2t $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -6\cos^2(x)+8\cos^4(x)-8t\cos^4(x)+8t\cos(x) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  8\cos^4(x)-8t\cos^4(x) +8t\cos(x)-6\cos^2(x) $$

Denominator:

$$ \sin(\frac{\pi}{6} +x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} -x) + t\sin^2(x) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  (\frac{\cos(x)}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}\sin(x)}{2})(\frac{\cos(x)}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}\sin(x)}{2}) + t\sin^2(x) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} (\cos^2(x)-3\sin^2(x))+t(1-\cos^2(x)) $$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} ( \cos^2(x)-3(1-\cos^2(x)) +t-t\cos^2(x) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} (4\cos^2(x)-3)+t-t\cos^2(x) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \cos^2(x) - \frac{3}{4}+t-t\cos^2(x) $$

Now I am stuck, how should I proceed?

Wolfram states it could be reduced to: $8\cos^2(x)$

Comment: You can use $2x=3x-x$ and $4x=3x-x$ to convert summation to product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the identities:

$\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B$

$\cos^{2}(x)+\sin^{2}(x)=1$

$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin(2x)$

For the denominator:

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} +x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6} -x) + t\sin^2(x)$

$=\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{6})-\sin^{2}(x)+t\sin^{2}(x)=\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{6})+(t-1)\sin^{2}(x)=\frac{1 }{4}+(t-1)\sin^{2}(x)$

For the numerator:

$\cos(2x)-(t-1)\cos(4x)+t$

$=\cos(2x)+(1-t)\cos(4x)+t$

$=1-2\sin^{2}(x)+(1-t)(1-2\sin^{2}(2x))+t$

$=1-2\sin^{2}(x)+(1-t)+2(t-1)(\sin^{2}(2x))+t$

$=2-2\sin^{2}(x)+2(t-1)(\sin^{2}(2x))$

$=2\cos^{2}(x)+2(t-1)(4\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x))$

$=2\cos^{2}(x)(1+4(t-1)\sin^{2}(x))$

So Now we have:

$\frac{2\cos^{2}(x)(1+4(t-1)\sin^{2}(x))}{\frac{1 }{4}+(t-1)\sin^{2}(x)}=\frac{8\cos^{2}(x)(1+4(t-1)\sin^{2}(x))}{1+4(t-1)\sin^{2}(x)}=8\cos^{2}(x)$

As sought.

Answer (score 1):

A general method to do this is by verifying $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f=0$. But this method seems to be a little unwieldy in this question. One may want just simplify the expression to get result.
To achieve such a goal, we need to make the denominator and numerator in the same form. It's not hard to observe they can both be simplified to a polynomial of $\cos(2x)$.
More precisely, we have
\begin{align}\text{numerator} & =\cos(2x)-(t-1)\cos(4x)+t\\
& =-2(t-1)\cos^2(2x)+\cos(2x)+2t-1\\
& = \big(\cos(2x)+1\big)\big(2(1-t)\cos(2x)+(2t-1)\big)
\end{align}
while
\begin{align}
\text{denominator} & = \frac 1 4 \cos^2 x-\frac 3 4 \sin^2 x+t\sin^2 x\\
& = \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac 1 2 (1+\cos(2x))-\frac 3 4 \cdot \frac 1 2(1-\cos(2x))+t\cdot\frac 1 2(1-\cos(2x))\\
& = \frac{1-t}{2}\cos(2x)+ \frac{2t-1}{4}\\
& = \frac 1 4\big(2(1-t)\cos(2x)+(2t-1)\big)
\end{align}
And we see $\text{numerator}/\text{denominator}=4\big(\cos(2x)+1\big)$. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Cross multiplication shows that
$$
\frac{a+bt}{c+dt}=\frac ac\iff ad=bc
$$
Therefore, it is sufficient to show that
$$
\sin^2(x)\,(\cos(2x)+\cos(4x))=(1-\cos(4x))\,\sin\left(\frac\pi6+x\right)\sin\left(\frac\pi6-x\right)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\sin^2(x)\,\overbrace{\left(2\cos^2(2x)+\cos(2x)-1\right)}^{(2\cos(2x)-1)(\cos(2x)+1)}=2\sin^2(2x)\,\left(\cos^2(x)-\frac34\right)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\sin^2(x)\,\left(4\cos^2(x)-3\right)\,2\cos^2(x)=8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\,\left(\cos^2(x)-\frac34\right)
$$
which is true.